# Laptop not being able to comeback when restarts. Not powering on after restart

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure, hp-elitebook

​Hello Everyone,

​I hope you can help me with this issues. I will tell you specifically what is the problem. I'm using HP Elitebook 2570p i7 3rd gen with 8GB of RAM, 500GB HDD and not having a battery .This is the problem, It takes time to boot and if does not I will repeat these process, turn off the laptop, disconnect the AC adapter and disconnect the ram. In many case it will not boot until 10 minutes. But sometimes it boots, when it boots no "display" but there's some lights on, blinking light on capslack in keyboard area, and I heard the fan spinning fast. No display after all but does have a "power", It will take forever if I don't press the shutdown button. Else, there's some instances that the laptop seems good, but I know it's not feeling well. I felt some little ground(electricity) in its topcover when AC adapter is connected. Overall the condition is not good, infrequent boots.

Now this is the weird part, I noticed  every time I installed a new program It won't let the laptop come back on after the "restart" option especially when prompt to restart. The only thing happens when restarting is no display, the light of power,browser,wifi LED indicators were all blinking for 1-2 seconds then dies.  Basically speaking when it's bout to restart it will not comeback (not booting) just totally shutdown. I also tried in cmd: "shutdown/r" or by manually restart and It just directly shutdown I don't know why. That's only happens when to installed a new program or software. It's pissed me off, because since It's hard to boot. Does anyone has the same experience with HP laptops?

Comment: not having a battery .  ...  I felt some little ground(electricity) in its topcover when AC adapter is connected.    .....   You need to replace the battery (laptops generally do not work properly without a battery) and get it serviced so the AC adapter is working correctly.

Comment: With or without battery it still the same case, It happens before. Thanks to your replies

Comment: You need to get the machine serviced at this point

Comment: Yeah I think so. But this time I can't, because I'll needing the machine for my work, and I will firstly confirm my suspicion about the board, for sure this is an corrupted bios chip.